# Automate replace function on multiple rows and multiple dataset

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 2 colums in my sheet.
column1 has the correct text
column2 has multiple variants of text correspondent to column1
I need a script on column3( or different sheet) that replaces the text entered ( if the text is found in column2) with the text from column1

I would like to use 2 sheets for this automation and the reason is. Column1 and 2 act as a database where i can modify, add or delete. Column3 on different sheet where I can populate daily and get automated replace.

Hope that makes sense. I am not a programmer or anything.
Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programmer's question and answer site. We do not accept free code requests. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/ for the type of questions, you're expected to ask here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: I vote to close. Since there is no feedback. Not to mention that the 'question' doesn't met the requirements of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() != 'Work') return;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return;

  var data = e.source.getSheetByName('Base').getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = data.find(x => x[0] == e.value);
  
  if (row.length > 0) {
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).setValue(row[1]);
  }
}
```

The script supposes that you have two sheets: 'Base' sheet (two columns, see the screenshot) and 'Work' sheet. Whenever you change a cell in column 'A' on the 'Work' sheet (empty). Whenever you change cell in column 'A' of 'Work' sheet it checks if the column 'A' of 'Base' sheet has the same text as the changed cell and changes the text of the cell with the text from column 'B' of 'Base' sheet.

[image]